# Unknown validator: 'InValidator' on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the official [getting started](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-concerns) guide of Ruby on Rails. The guide provides the following code to add status validation to the concern:

```
module Visible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    VALID_STATUSES = ['public', 'private', 'archived']

    validates :status, in: VALID_STATUSES
  end

  def archived?
    status == 'archived'
  end
end
```

However I get the following error: `Unknown validator: 'InValidator'` on line `validates :status, in: VALID_STATUSES`. I am using Rails 6.1.0 and following the guide for this version exactly. What is the problem here?

**Edit**
I have done a small change to make it work: `validates :status, inclusion: { in: VALID_STATUSES }`. But I want to know why `in` is not working as in the guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guide seems to be wrong, your solution with changing it to `inclusion: { in: [] }` is correct.

There is already a fix merged in the [Rails repository](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40826) but seems not yet deployed.

To add some background information how this works, the [implementation in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L119) does instantiate the validator class [which is called InclusionValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/inclusion.rb#L7).